# How do I make a gif disappear after it's done on blackberry java?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, gif

I know how to load in a gif and let it run but how do you make it disappear?

Ie. it's on top of another bitmap background and looks like its interacting with the background, I want it to go away after its finished one time through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the gif to non-repeating and make the final frame 100% transparent.

Comment: how exactly do I do that? The class I'm using only allows the gif and style as parameters. I got it here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Display-an-animated-GIF/ta-p/445014

Comment: I mean, edit your actual gif so that after it finishes there's a new frame that is entirely transparent pixels.

Comment: oh good idea, thanks! Any thoughts on how to make it not repeat? or is that in the creation of it as well (I've just been experimenting with premade gifs so far)

Comment: That's part of the GIF itself, yeah. You can open it in Photoshop and edit it, but I don't remember how; I think you just set the timing to 'once' in the animation bar.